# Insert Incrament In Existing Array

Tags: python, sql

I have an existing python3 tuple withdrawn from an sqlite3 table with dates "??-??-22" per row in accordance with the insertion date.
I would like to insert another element in the python3 tuple that matches the date properly. In this case, an increment of a day number matching the date change.
The number of rows per day are sometimes inconsistent. Hence, I am not inserting tuple back into database....Just using it for data visualization.

For example,
[('06-08-22',otherData), ('06-08-22',), ('06-08-22',), ('06-08-22',), ('06-08-22',), ('06-09-22',), ('06-09-22',), ('06-09-22',),  ...etc )]

------>>>

[('06-08-22',Day Number Here,), ('06-08-22',1,), ('06-08-22',1,), ('06-08-22',1,), ('06-08-22',1,), ('06-09-22',2,), ('06-09-22',2,), ('06-09-22',2,),  ...etc )]

Solve by a for loop? Feels like overlooking something simple.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot insert new elements into a tuple, so you will have to convert each tuple to a list and then back to a tuple (or just leave them as lists if you don't really need them to stay tuples)

```
data = [
    ('06-08-22', 'A'),
    ('06-08-22', 'B'),
    ('06-09-22', 'C'),
    ('06-10-22', 'D'),
    ('06-10-22', 'E')
]


def transform_data(rows):
    day_num = 0
    last_date = None
    for row in rows:
        lst = list(row)
        if lst[0] != last_date:
            last_date = lst[0]
            day_num += 1
        lst.insert(1, day_num)
        yield tuple(lst)


for row in transform_data(data):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
('06-08-22', 1, 'A')
('06-08-22', 1, 'B')
('06-09-22', 2, 'C')
('06-10-22', 3, 'D')
('06-10-22', 3, 'E')
```